# Shift + down macro code

Tags: excel, macros, vba

Good Day,

Is there any code for Shift + Down? i tried so many codes but I'm not able to figure it out. I also used the Offset code, but i don't have luck.
what i am trying to do is something like this,

```
Range("J3").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(1, 0)(xlDown)).Select
```

I am not really sure using the offset on the range but I hope it will give you the idea on what I am asking

thank you so much and regards

P.s 
this is not the CTRL + Shift + Down `Selection.End(xldown).Select` :)

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore the query, I came up with this and it worked.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(1, 0)).Select
```

What i did is i just deleted the (xldown)

thanks